# Panda code error in Jupyter - TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When I run following code, the code runs perfectly.

[image]

But when I run the following code, I get the following error.

[image]

These two codes are not different that much.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: The error basically is telling that "i" is just a float data and not an array. The code has no errors, you might have executed a different part of code which might have changed genre_series

Comment: `print (i)` to see what you have in `i` - it seems you have single number and you try to do ie. `len(3.1415)`. Maybe both codes are not different but you can have different values in `genre_series` in both situations.

Comment: No, that's the crazy thing. In both codes, genre_series have the same values.

Comment: Found the error. There were some null values in genre column.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. There were some NULL values in the genre column. When I printed it, it got printed. But when I did len(), it showed error for some values.

Comment: So what's the solution? Did you change your data? Please elaborate, then accept your answer so the question is resolved.